# Rowspan in the last row of the table with CSS and without CSS

Tags: html

I am trying to draw the below image 
[image]

I am not able to get the image by using table in html. I have tried using rowspan but it just distorts the table and doesnot create the required result. How can I get the table without using CSS and with using CSS.

Further can we apply rowspan to the last row of the table ? if we can then how ? can someone give an example for the usage also.

Comment: If this needs to be dynamic you need to use JS - something like [Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: I am not aware of this. But if you want you can share the answer that way we may come to know of new method and dynamic table.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you haven't set the cell highs, this is a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/danielillo/full/maVeYE) example.

While the cells are empty you must set the cell height. It can be removed once the cells have their content: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/danielillo/full/WLwNRw).

```
<table width="300" border="1px solid">
<tr>
<td width="33%" height="100"></td>
<td width="33%" height="100"></td>
<td width="33%" height="100"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="33%" height="100"></td>
<td width="33%" height="200" rowspan="2"></td>
<td width="33%" height="100"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="33%" height="200" rowspan="2"></td>
<td width="33%" height="200" rowspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="33%" height="100"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

There are some online table generators that can help you: https://www.tablesgenerator.com

Comment: thanks. This works for the result I was requiring.

Comment: For more clarity can you explain why we are using height and rowspan together ? Will not rowspan=2 work to double the height of the cell ?

Comment: Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table width="400" height="300" border="2" >
    <tr>
        <td align="center">1</td>
        <td align="center">2</td>
        <td align="center">3</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="center">4</td>
        <td align="center" rowspan="2">5</td>
        <td align="center">6</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="center" rowspan="2">7</td>
        <td align="center" rowspan="2">9</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="center">8</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```